# Logic of beforeValidate() in sails.js

Tags: sails.js

I am new to sails.js, and after some works I find `beforeValidate()` hard to use.

I have a model `User` with just 2 attributes `nickname` and `age`. 
Both attributes are marked as `required` so sails will check the validation. 
When creating an user, if the client does not specify its nickname, I would like to assign a random nickname to it, as following:

```
beforeValidate: function(user, next){
    if (!user.nickname) user.nickname = randomString(5);
    next();
}
```

This assigning should be applied before sails validates the `required` tag of `nickname`, so the `beforeValidate()` seems to be the only reasonable place to do it.
However, when I want to update an user's age like:

```
User.update(user.id, {age: 40});
```

It will also trigger `beforeValidate()` and, sadly, a new nickname will be assigned and replace the origin one, since the parameter `user` in `beforeValidate()` now is `{age: 40}`.

What I expect is that the parameter `user` in `beforeValidate(user, callback)` should be updated user, the combination of both changed and unchanged attributes (e.g. user with old id, old nickname and new age), instead of only changed attributes that I specify in `User.update()` (e.g. only `{age: 40}`).

Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: I find that `defaultTo` can be a function, so my purpose can be satisfied though. However, I still want to know why `user` parameter in `beforeValidate()` is not the full user record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While calling `create()` all the values required to add a new record get passed to `beforeValidate`. Whereas while calling `update()` only the values that are getting updated are passed to `beforeValidate`. This is the reason you are getting `user.nickname` as empty value.

Refer to the docs at http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks.

> **Callbacks on create**
>
> beforeValidate: fn(values, cb)
>
> **Callbacks on update**
>
> beforeValidate: fn(valuesToUpdate, cb)